# Parse boolean condition into expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

If I have a method that takes a boolean like:

```
public void Foo(boolean condition)
```

And call it like this:

```
Foo("MyField" == "MyValue");
```

Can I compose that into an expression tree in order to construct a query to some other datasource that will use MyField as one parameter and MyValue and another.
I can only seem to make that condition into a expression that evaluates to false.

**UPDATE**

```
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Field), field);
    var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Name");

    ConstantExpression @const = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var body = Expression.Equal(prop, @const);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Field, bool>>(body, param);
```

Where Field is a class with two properties, Name and Value

Comment: I think you have a bug in your "UPDATE": the second parameter to `Expression.Parameter` is just the *logical name of the parameter* - so passing in `field` looks very wrong. Likewise, using the constant literal `"Name"` as the field/property looks... unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo("MyField" == "MyValue")` is, as noted at the bottom of the question, a constant `false` (right up at the compiler). You have a few choices here - the simplest of course is to do something like:

```
void Foo(Expression<Func<YourType,bool>> predicate) {...}
```

and call with

```
Foo(x => x.MyField == "MyValue");
```

then *here*, there is nothing left to do; we already have the expression. So I assume you mean "MyField" is a string only known at runtime, in which case:

```
void Foo<T>(string fieldName, T value) {
   var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(YourType), "x");
   var body = Expression.Equal(
                  Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName),
                  Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T))
               );
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<YourType, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

and call with `Foo("MyField", "MyValue)` (with an implicit `<string>` in there, courtesy of the compiler), or `Foo("MyField", 123)` if the prop is an `int` (implicit `<int>`),

The final scenario is where `"MyValue"` is also a **string** only known at runtime (emph: `string`) - in which case we'll need to parse it:

```
void Foo(string fieldName, string value) {
   var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(YourType), "x");
   var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
   ConstantExpression @const;
   if(prop.Type == typeof(string)) {
       @const = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
   } else {
       object parsed = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(prop.Type)
           .ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
       @const = Expression.Constant(parsed, prop.Type);
   }
   var body = Expression.Equal(prop,@const);
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<YourType, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

Here the call is always 2 strings - so `Foo("MyField", "123")` even when `int`.

Comment: +1 Great answer, I had to modify it slightly though as in my edit...thanks!

Comment: @Johan - anything specific failing? Also, if you know `"Name"` ahead of time, you can just use `x => x.Name == value`...?

Comment: When I used x it failed saying that x is not a known property of Field...ideas?

Comment: @Johan yes, I think you have mixed up the parameters to `Expression.Parameter` and `Expression.PropertyOrField` - the *parameter* should be called (something like) `x` - the property should typically vary

Answer (score 1):

In can create expression trees from delegates. For example, if you define your method so that it takes a delegate as a parameter, you can use it as follows:

```
public void Foo(Func<bool> fn)
{
    // invoke the passed delegate
    var result = fn();
}

Foo(() => "MyField" == "MyValue");
```

In order to create an expression tree, rather than execute the delegate, change the method as follows:

```
public void Foo(Expression<Func<bool>> expression)
{
   // inspect your expression tree here
}
```

However, in your case, you will find that your expression is a boolean constant with a value of 'false', this is because the compiler has evaluated `"MyField" == "MyValue"` which is of course false.

If you just want name-value pairs, which not just use a `Dictionary<string, string>` ?

Comment: +1. Good answer, with one slight inaccuracy: the name `action` suggests an `Action` delegate type -- ie. `delegate void ()` -- and not a `Func<T>`. I'd rename that identifier to e.g. `fn` or `lazyBool`, or something similar.

Comment: "In can create expression trees from delegates" - er, no it can't